# Flutter Change pictures

Tags: flutter, package, slider, carousel-slider

worth the package "flutter_carousel_slider", CarouselSlider is assigned to OnTap, it opens and you cannot scroll left and right to change images, can I do that somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find CarouselSlider widget from your code. I've added the widget with its properties.

```
CarouselSlider(
   items: items,
   options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 400,
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      reverse: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   )
 )
```